# Connecting oracle data base from C program using pro*c

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I want to try execute SQL statement from a C program using pro*c.

I have tried installing oracle Database from
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle19c-windows-downloads.html

It consist of zipped file.

I just extracted the zip file into my C:/oracle directory.
The directory already consist of precompile folder.
I set path variable to C:/oracle/bin/  .

For checking installation of proc compiler, I ran "proc" command, but it produces the following error.

```
C:\PJT>proc


PCC-F-NOERRFILE, unable to open error message file, facility PR2
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have skipped a few steps; but installation and management of a database are not on-topic here. The specific error means you haven't set up your environment - specifically ORACLE_HOME. But I'd suggest you find and follow a tutorial on how to get started with Oracle, before jumping to Pro*C. Maybe start with [the installation guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntdbi/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Alex, Actually the main task is to access the oracle DB located in the remote PC using pro*c. I will go through the installation guide.

Comment: If this is a temporary or experimental thing then you might be better off with [the 18c XE](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html) version, or [a pre-built VM](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html), or one of the free online offerings, like [the Oracle Cloud free tier](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/?source=:ow:o:s:nav:062520GlobalNavProducts&intcmp=:ow:o:s:nav:062520GlobalNavProducts) - depending on what you are allowed to install or access.

Comment: Ok I solved the error, it seems like the oracle DB is not installed properly. Running the setup file automatically sets required environment paths. Earlier this setup file is not running properly.

Comment: Your question implied you wanted a local DB. If you *only* want to connect to a remote DB you don't need the full DB server installation; you can install just the client, or even instant client - you just need the additional elements for SDK and precompiler options.